# Bent shimano 12 speed slx m7100 rear derailleur. Cause?

Tags: derailleur

Rear derailleur (mileage: 600 miles) simply bent during my ride (I didn't crash and didn't notice something hitting rear mech). Bend is significant. It seems to me that the derailleur cage is bent, not the hanger. I also noticed that the clutch needs oil / replacement. I know that replacing the derailleur is the only solution (if the hanger is really straight). I am trying to spot a cause of this issue for future reference. What could have caused this bend? Worn clutch? Wrong chain line?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you take a photo of the cage straight-on? The 12 speed Shimano derailleurs actually have some degree of bend built in to improve the chain line. How well does it shift?

Comment: Are you sure that the hanger isn’t bent. It doesn’t take much bend at the hanger to present at the cage like that. In any case a little controlled bending by hand at the derailleur/hanger bolt  might improve the situation.

Comment: Make sure the mounting bolt isn't loose.

Comment: @MaplePanda - updated. It shifts like poorly on larger cogs. I can't access first and second gear, because it crashes with spokes.

Comment: The clutch stops the derailer cage from moving forward when you hit bumps. I don’t think the clutch needing service should cause the derailer to tilt towards the spokes. Some service instructions are here, though: https://www.singletracks.com/mtb-repair/how-to-service-your-shimano-derailleur-clutch/

Comment: If you have a quick release wheel make sure it's in the dropouts properly

Comment: @Michal You can try disassembling the derailleur, removing the cage plates, and manually bending them straight. Although to be fair, if you really were just riding along when it bent by itself, I would contact shimano’s warranty, or at least your bike manufacturer. Here’s the service manual: https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-MARD001-03-ENG.pdf